# How to prevent leakage of installed Chrome Browser extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, privacy, fingerprint

Basis for my question is this study:
https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity17/sec17-sanchez-rola.pdf

Relevant quotes from the study:

"The extension detection works by trying to detect resources, such as icons, that extensions use. All the site does is therefore check whether resources exist. If they do, it knows that there is a high probability that the extension is installed."

"Another method that it uses abuses Content-Security Policy by using the feature to determine whether contents get loaded, or not."

"discovered a way to enumerate installed browser extensions in the newest versions of web browsers. The "timing side-channel attack" may be used to enumerate the installed browser extensions by monitoring the browser's response to resource access."

"The site measures the time it takes to return a request for a fake extension with fake resource and the time it takes to request a real extension with a fake path.
By comparing the time, installed extensions are revealed."

**

> My question:

**

**How to prevent websites from gathering info on installed Chrome extensions?** Are there any Chrome settings which could be changed to achieve that? Any other ideas?

Disabling Javascript is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

As the linked paper notes, this is not a new issue but part of a general issue that has been affecting all browsers implementing any kind of extension for some time now.

After the first version of Chrome extensions was found to be vulnerable, Google added a security mechanism in the second version to prevent access to extension resources except where explictly allowed. From the same document:

> In the first version of the manifest, there was no restriction over
> the resources of the extensions accessible from third-party websites.
> Because of that, different tools were released to take advantage of
> this weakness to enumerate user extensions and exploit their
> vulnerabilities [23]. To mitigate this threat, Google decided to
> introduce dedicated access control settings in the second version of
> the manifest file. This extension uses a parameter (web accessible
> resources) to specify the paths of packaged resources that can be used
> in the context of a website. Resources are available through the URL
> chrome-extension://[extID]/[path]. However, any navigation access to
> an extension or its resources is blocked by the browser, unless the
> extension resource has been previously listed as accessible in its
> manifest.json. This solution was explicitly designed to minimize the
> attack surface while protecting users’ privacy.

It seems reasonable to expect that Google are continuing to monitor the situation and will introduce further enhancements if that becomes necessary.

However, since version 2, the extension mechanism gives us visibility of which extensions allow their resources to be accessed over the web, which means we do have a way to prevent this security issue without disabling JavaScript: we can uninstall any extension that exposes resources in this way.

The information about whether an extension exposes a resource can be found in the extension's manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
"images/*.png",
"style/double-rainbow.css",
"script/double-rainbow.js",
"script/main.js",
"templates/*"],
```

If you're not sure where to find the manifest files for your Chrome extensions, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862215/what-is-a-manifest-json-file-and-where-can-i-find-it-on-my-machine) has answers for Windows, Mac and Linux.